# %d placeholder input '3abc', cannot clear 'abc' buffer

Tags: c, buffer, stdin, flush

Below is my code:

```
int length;
char ch;

printf("\n\tEnter the length of the password: ");
while (scanf("%d", &length) != 1) {

    printf("\n\tPlease enter digit only.\n");
    printf("\n\tEnter the length of the password: ");

    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
}

printf("\n\tEnter the number of passwords you want: ");
while (scanf("%d", &num) != 1) {

    printf("\n\tPlease enter digit only.\n");
    printf("\n\tEnter the number of passwords you want: ");

    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
}
```

When I entered `abc` okay.

When I entered `3abc`, 3 is received by length, but the 'abc' still in the buffer.

I used `while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);` to clear but still not working?

Any help from the expert is appreciated.

Comment: Have you declared `ch` as an `int`?

Comment: `char ch;` <-- my declaration. Sorry, edited.

Comment: to recognize `ch != EOF` `ch` **must be** `int`...

Comment: **getchar** returns int type. see prototype : `int getchar(void)`

Comment: `scanf("%d%c", &length, &ch) != 2 || ch != '\n'`

Comment: @LPs @rsp I tried to change to `int ch` but not working.

Comment: Or comment does not refers to the problem you are asking for, but it is one of the problem of your code.

Comment: @LPs Because I have other scanf below so after entered `3abc` I cannot enter the next input, I tried @BLUEPIXY method, working but still got little bug, I posted soon

Comment: the posted code does not compile!   There is no function defined.  There is no `#include` for the header file `stdio.h` needed for `getchar()`, `scanf()`, and `printf()`

Comment: you could insert the statement to clear `stdin` after getting out of the first loop, However, that would also consume the second data/digit input.  Suggest read in whole line with: `fgets()` then parsing the input.  if the desired second data/digit was not found, then call `fgets()` again to get the second data/digit from the user.

Comment: @user3629249 Sorry I remove the `#include` for the sake of simplification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not flushing the `stdin` if a number was correctly grabbed by `scanf` as your test case `3asc`

```
 int length;
 int ch;

 printf("\n\tEnter the length of the password: ");
 while (scanf("%d", &length) != 1) {

     printf("\n\tPlease enter digit only.\n");
     printf("\n\tEnter the length of the password: ");

     while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
 }

 // flush stdin
 while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);

 printf("\n\tEnter the number of passwords you want: ");
 while (scanf("%d", &length) != 1) {

     printf("\n\tPlease enter digit only.\n");
     printf("\n\tEnter the number of passwords you want: ");

     while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
 }
```

And, already commented, to recognize `ch != EOF` `ch` **must be** `int`. Moreover getchar prototype is [int getchar(void)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar)

Comment: the proposed answer will not work.  When the user enters `#...#...` then the clearing of `stdin` between the two loops will consume the second data item. Not what is wanted.

Comment: @user3629249 First of all, thanks for commenting your DV: it's quite rare nowadays. Second: who told you that the expected behavior is what you are guessing? For what we know OP is asking for accepting one-input-per-newline, that is what OP achieve with my proposed (and accepted) solution.

Comment: I may have misread this statement by the OP: *When I entered 3abc, 3 is received by length, but the 'abc' still in the buffer.* to mean that the whole thing was being entered on a single line (which the OPs posted code would allow.)

Answer (score 1):

If `scanf()` is successful, what is inside the loop is not executed ... so if you enter "3abc", `scanf()` reads the '3' and "abc" is still in the input buffer because you don't go into the loop